# How to display a message after login

Tags: linux, bash

As the title says, I have modified the .bash_profile with and echo command, but I want the message to be taken from a file and I haven't been successful until now.

Edit: Thanks for your answers, but I believe I haven't explained myself correctly. The message is already present in a specific file, which is different for each user. I can use the file's location but I can't edit another file.

Comment: Most GNU/Linux distributions offer the classical "message of the day" feature. If you want to implement something yourself using bash commands take a look at `cat` and use it instead of `echo` to display the contents of a file.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this (I removed the silly `<`...) -

```
cat /path/to/file
```

Answer (score 4):

On most Linux systems there are two text files you can edit to display a message at login.

- Before login: `/etc/issue`
- After login: `/etc/motd`